# Permanently Change Disassembly Flavor in GDB

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, gdb, intel-syntax

How can I permanently change the disassembly flavor in GDB.  I tried:`set disassembly-flavor intel` in GDB, but when I fire up GDB later it still has the att flavor.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

gdb executes a `~/.gdbinit` file when it starts, if present. You can add this line to it:

```
set disassembly-flavor intel
```

From the shell, this command will append that line, creating the file if it doesn't exist:

```
echo "set disassembly-flavor intel" >> ~/.gdbinit
```

The GDB manual's page on machine code and disassembly [documents the command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Machine-Code.html#index-set-disassembly_002dflavor), and that the default is `set disassembly-flavor att`.

---

For more tips on asm debugging in GDB, like `layout reg`+`layout next`, or `layout asm` TUI mode, see the debugging section at the bottom of [the x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

The chosen `disassembly-flavor` is used for the disassembly pane in `asm` and asm+reg layouts, as well as for `disas` and `x /i` commands.

Comment: I did not have a ~/.gdbinit file, but I created one and added set disassembly-flavor intel to it.  Worked Thanks!

Comment: My config file was located at `~/.config/gdb/gdbinit`. Try that file if this didn't work!