# Where is GDB's gdbinit file when using cygwin?

Tags: debugging, gdb, cygwin, gnu

I would like to follow the answer in this question:

[Permanently Change Disassembly Flavor in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569285/permanently-change-disassembly-flavor-in-gdb)

but it refers to a GDB file named .gdbinit. What is the equivalent file when using GDB through cygwin?

Answer (score 1):

gdb help output tells you where it's looking at startup:

```
$ gdb --help | tail
                     Set GDB's data-directory to DIR.

At startup, GDB reads the following init files and executes their commands:
   * user-specific init file: /home/davidw/.gdbinit
   * local init file (see also 'set auto-load local-gdbinit'): ./.gdbinit

For more information, type "help" from within GDB, or consult the
GDB manual (available as on-line info or a printed manual).
Report bugs to "<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>".
```

You can also get a little more information from within gdb with the command 
`show autoload`.

See also the online manual [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Startup.html).

Not really relevant to this question, but the reason I spent time looking into this was that, with cygwin, my .gdbinit seemd to be getting ignored. It turned out to be the command in my .gdbinit that was being [ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176800/how-can-i-make-gdb-save-the-command-history).

Comment: btw cygwin used to have it's own .gdbinit file call `gdb.ini` if I do `touch ~/gdb.ini` then gdb will no longer start.