# How to make Eclipse disassemble the code in Intel syntax

Tags: eclipse, assembly, eclipse-cdt, disassembly

I use Eclise CDT as a development environment. I use disassembly view to see assembly equivalents. But I am used to read an write assembly code in Intel syntax. Is there any option to make the Eclipse dump the assembly code in Intel syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a file with `set disassembly-flavor intel` in it, you can use `~/.gdbinit` as the file if you want.

Then point your launch configuration at the file you created.

Without the launch configuration change your disassembly may look like:

```
15                  puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
000000000040053a:   mov     $0x4005d4,%edi
000000000040053f:   callq   0x400410 <puts@plt>
```

With the gdb init file you get the Intel syntax:

```
15                  puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
000000000040053a:   mov     edi,0x4005d4
000000000040053f:   call    0x400410 <puts@plt>
```

Note CDT does not pick up `~/.gdbinit` unless you explicitly set it in the launch configuration. Here is a screenshot of the launch configuration:

[image]

### Globally

You can make the change global (for all new launch configurations at least) by setting the GDB command file in the preferences too:

[image]

Credit to [Permanently Change Disassembly Flavor in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569285/permanently-change-disassembly-flavor-in-gdb) for the GDB part of the change.