# How to change the disassembly syntax to intel using gdb?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, disassembly, intel-syntax

```
(gdb) set disassemble intel
Ambiguous set command "disassemble intel": disassemble-next-line, disassembler-options.
```

When i set the disassembly syntax to intel, it show this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permanently Change Disassembly Flavor in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569285/permanently-change-disassembly-flavor-in-gdb)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Please use:

```
set disassembly-flavor intel
```

see [GDB Manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Machine-Code.html#index-set-disassembly_002dflavor) for more details

For a more permanent change please look: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569285/permanently-change-disassembly-flavor-in-gdb)

Comment: Thanks. But after setting it, disassemble main inside gdb shows in AT&T syntax, which have % or $ symbols.

Comment: The change is temporary, after i set and close gdb, show disassembly returns 'att' which is not correct.

Comment: Should be fixed now

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: The older question ([Permanently Change Disassembly Flavor in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8569285)) has a more complete answer; I edited it recently.  Unfortunately I didn't dup-hammer it before editing tags, and the one original tag I kept isn't one I have a gold badge in.

Comment: @Peter I your link to my question.

Answer (score 21):

To make the change permanent you must add it to your `gdb` config file:

```bash
echo "set disassembly-flavor intel" >> ~/.gdbinit
```

Then run:

```bash
cat  ~/.gdbinit
```

to make sure the file has the proper content.

Comment: You'll probably want to use `>>` to avoid overwriting existing content.