# x64 Assembly reverse string function

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse

I'm learning assembly and facing the following problem:

In the function

```
asm_func4:
        push rbp                ; preserve rbp
        call _strlen            ; get rdi strlen
        mov rdx, rax            ; copy strlen to reverse counter 
        sub rdx, 2              ; remove \n and 0h 
        xor rcx, rcx            ; clear counter        

_reverse_str:
        mov al, [rdi+rdx]       ; copy last char to al
        mov byte [rsi+rcx], al  ; copy al to rsi 
        inc rcx                 ; increment destination counter
        dec rdx                 ; decrement reverse counter 
        jnz  _reverse_str       ; not zero? do it again

_reverse_end:
        mov byte [rsi+rcx], 0h  ; null-terminate the string
        mov rax,rsi             ; copy to rax to return the func
        pop rbp                 ; must be preserved
        ret
```

I'm getting a `SIGSEGV` while executing the line `mov byte [rsi+rcx], al  ; copy al to rsi'.
What am I doing wrong here?

This is the `gdb' info:

```
0x0000555555555317 in _reverse_str ()
1: (char *) $rdi = 0x555555556086 "Hello from asm_func4\n"
2: (char *) $rsi = 0x55555555609b ""
3: (char *) $rax = 0x34 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x34>
4: (char) $al = 52 '4'
5: (int) $rcx = 0
6: (int) $rdx = 19
(gdb) x/i $pc
=> 0x555555555317 <_reverse_str+3>: mov    %al,(%rsi,%rcx,1)
(gdb) stepi

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

The function is being called from C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "prog.h"


int main(void)
{

    printf("%s", asm_func4("Hello from asm_func4\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

And prog.h is:

```
#pragma once
 char* asm_func4(char *);
```

Comment: 0x555555556086 is only one page later than your code.  Are you sure it's in a writeable page? e.g. in `.data`, not `.rodata` where compilers put string literals?  The store address is `rsi+rcx  = rsi+0` according to your GDB register dump, and that's in the same page that GDB was able to read the string from.

Comment: Also note [How to change the disassembly syntax to intel using gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55040576) - you can have it disassemble using Intel syntax, much less confusing when writing in NASM.

Comment: 0x555555556086 contains the string received from a "C" prog. I'm still a newbie so I'm not sure how to answer your question about that being in a writable page. I have a `.data` section at the end of the file, used by another function, not this one. How do I make sure rsi is pointing to a writable page? Tks

Comment: How does the C program look like? You know that string literals are constant, right? So if you have something like `asm_func4("Hello from asm_func4\n")` that won't work. Also calling convention says `rdi` is call clobbered register so after you do `call _strlen` you can't rely on its value.

Comment: So your C program declares it as a non-const array, right, like `char str[] = "Hello from asm_func4\n";`?  Not like `const char *str = "...";`, a pointer to a read-only string literal.  Or if you declare the data in asm, and reference it from C via `extern char str4[];` that's also fine, as long as it's in `.data`.  Anyway, this isn't a [mcve] since you're missing details on how the string was allocated.

Comment: Didn't know that string literals are constants, tks for that. The C call is exactly as you wrote: `asm_func4("Hello from asm_func4\n")`. I wrote `_strlen` and know that `rdi` isn't touched. Even with that should I treat `rdi` as unreliable?

Comment: I'm not allocating anything, just calling `printf("%s", asm_func4("Hello from asm_func4\n"));`. Just to confirm my understanding: 'rsi' is pointing to a read-only page, right? I'm not allocating any space in `.data`, should I do that?

Comment: You don't even set `rsi` to anything.

Comment: I assume your custom `_strlen` function copies RDI to RSI, and returns RSI as a pointer to the end of the string, as well as leaving RDI unmodified?  Your `asm_func4` relies on that without even mentioning it in a comment.  (But you're reversing in-place, not into a possibly-separate destination, so IDK why you'd have two different registers holding pointers *as well* as two different registers holding indexes to offset from them.  The normal way is to `inc rdi` / `dec rsi` and stop when they cross in the middle, like `do{}while(++head < --tail);`